# CakePHP Membership Management

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a 'Membership' model that keeps track of a Member's membership. A membership can be updated by an admin (admin_add), or by the user (update). This code is working great, but I'd love some feedback on how it looks, sections that could be improved, etc.

```
Membership Model: 

class Membership extends AppModel {


        /**
         * Validation rules
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public $validate = array(
                'membership_type_id' => array(
                        'notempty' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Membership Type Required',
                                'allowEmpty' => false,
                                'required' => true,
                        ),
                        'validateMembership' => array(
                                'rule' => 'validateMembershipTypeModel',
                                'message' => 'Invalid Membership Type',
                        ),
                ),
                'updated_by_member_id' => array(
                        'validateMember' => array(
                                'rule' => 'validateMemberId',
                                'message' => 'Invalid Updated By Member ID',
                                'allowEmpty' => true,
                        ),
                ),
                'payment_id' => array(
                        'validatePayment' => array(
                                'rule' => 'validatePayment',
                                'message' => 'Invalid Payment ID',
                                'allowEmpty' => true,
                        ),
                ),
                'expires' => array(
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid expiration date',
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'required' => true
            ), 
            'renewed' => array(
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid renewal date',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
            ), 
        );


        /*
        * Validation function to make sure the membership type id is valid
        *
        * @return bool
        */
        public function validateMembershipTypeModel($check) {

                $mTypeModel = ClassRegistry::init('MembershipType');
                if($mTypeModel->validateMembershipType($this->data['Membership']['membership_type_id'])) {
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
    }

    /*
        * Validation function to make sure the "updated_by_member_id" is valid (a valid member)
        *
        * @return bool
        */
        public function validateMemberId($check) {
                if(! isset($this->data['Membership']['updated_by_member_id'])) {
                        return false;
                }

                $mModel = ClassRegistry::init('Member');
                $mModel->contain();

                if($mModel->findById($this->data['Membership']['updated_by_member_id'])) {

                        return true;
                }

                return false;
    }

     /*
        * Validation function to make sure the payment ID is valid
        *
        * UPDATE
        *
        * @return bool
        */
        public function validatePayment($check) {
                return true;
    }

        /**
         * belongsTo associations
         *
         * @var type array
        */
        public $belongsTo = array(
                'Member',
                'MembershipType'
        );

        /*
        * Validate Membership Data
        *
        * return array membership data
        */
        public function _validateMembershipData($data = array()) {

                // Validate 'corporate' flag
                if(isset($data['corporate']) && $data['corporate'] == 'on') {
                        $data['corporate'] = 1;
                }

                // Validate 'international' flag
                if(isset($data['international']) && $data['international'] == 'on') {
                        $data['international'] = 1;
                }

                return $data;
        }

        /*
        * Create new membership
        * Anytime a membership is updated, this function is called
        *
        *
        * return integer membershipID
        */
        public function createNewMembership($data) {

                if(empty($data)) {
                        return false;
                }

                // Validate data
                $membership_data = $this->_validateMembershipData($data);

                $this->set($membership_data);
                if ($this->validates()) {

                        // Save data           
                        $this->create();
                        if(! $this->save($membership_data)) {
                                throw new NotFoundException('Could not find save membership');
                        }

                        // Assign the membership_id to the member
                        if(! $this->assignMembershipToMember($this->id, $data['member_id'])) {
                                throw new NotFoundException('Could not find save membership_id to member');
                        }

                        // Return Membership ID
                        return $this->id;
                }

                return false;
        }

        /*
        * Assign a membership id to a member
        *
        * param membership_id
        * param member id
        * return bool on success
        */
        public function assignMembershipToMember($membership_id, $member_id) {
                $member = ClassRegistry::init('Member');       
                $member->id = $member_id;

                if($member->saveField('membership_id', $membership_id)) {
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
        }

}


/**
 * Memberships Controller
 *
 * @property Membership $Membership
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 * @property SessionComponent $Session
 */
class MembershipsController extends AppController {

        public $uses = array('Member', 'Membership', 'MembershipType');

        /**
         * admin_update method - Update a member's Membership
         *
         * @throws NotFoundException
         * @param integer $id
         * @return void
         */
        public function admin_update($id = null) {

                // Validate the member id
                $this->Member->contain('Membership');
                $member = $this->Member->findById($id);

                if (! $this->Member->exists($id)) {
                        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid member'));
                }

                if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

                        // Fill in some of the membership data manually
                        $this->request->data['Membership']['updated_by_member_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                        $this->request->data['Membership']['member_id'] = $id;
                        $this->request->data['Membership']['renewed'] = date('Y-m-d');
                        $this->request->data['Membership']['created_by'] = 'MANUAL';

                        // Create the membership
                        if ($this->Membership->createNewMembership($this->request->data['Membership'])) {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Membership Updated.'), 'success');
                                return $this->redirect(array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'view', $id));
                        } else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('There was an error updating the membership. Please try again.'), 'error');
                        }
                } else {
                        $this->request->data = $this->Membership->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $member['Member']['membership_id'])));                     
                }

        }

        /**
         * update method - Update a member's Membership
         *
         * @throws NotFoundException
         * @param integer $id
         * @return void
         */
        public function update($membership_type_id = null) {

                // Validate the membership type id
                $this->MembershipType->contain();
                $membership_type = $this->MembershipType->findById($membership_type_id);
                if(! $membership_type) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Invalid Membership Type", 'error');
                        return $this->redirect('/');
                }

                // Set the member ID to the person logged in
                $memberId = $this->Auth->user('id');

                // If they are submitting
                if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                        // Assume true for testing
                        $payment = true;
                        $international = true;

                        if($payment === true) {

                                // Build the membership data
                                $membership_data = array(
                                        'member_id' => $memberId,
                                        'membership_type_id' => $membership_type_id,
                                        'renewed' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                        'expires' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 year")),
                                );

                                // Create a new membership
                                if($this->Membership->createNewMembership($membership_data)) {
                                        $this->Session->setFlash("Success! Your membership has been updated! Please make sure your address is correct below!", 'success');
                                        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'view'));
                                }  else {
                                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('There was an error updating the membership. Please try again.'), 'error');
                                }
                        }
                }

                $this->set(compact('membership_type'));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I would suggest you to do is to remove lines where you initialize models `MembershipType` and `Member` since you already have model associations set up correctly. For example, instead of:

```
$mTypeModel = ClassRegistry::init('MembershipType');
if ($mTypeModel->validateMembershipType($this->data['Membership']['membership_type_id'])) {
    return true;
}
```

you can do it like this:

```
if ($this->MembershipType->validateMembershipType($this->data['Membership']['membership_type_id'])) {
   return true;
}
```